# HTML link with embedded code to identify those who click clicked through and visited my site

Tags: html

I would like to send an email with an HTML link to drive people to my website.

Is there any way to embed code into the link that lets me know who actually clicked through and visited my site?

(Maybe if I can set variables as part of the html link, I could just send an email back to myself with the information when they click the "proceed" button?)

I am a very-beginner programmer with grand ideas. Any ideas you can throw my way would be greatly appreciated.

Becki

Answer (score 0):

One way you could go about doing this that I can think of is query strings.  If you have a list of emails, just number them off and give them different ref numbers.

Like this:

1. john@doe.com
2. jane@doe.com

http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html?ref=1

http://www.yourwebsite.com/page.html?ref=2

etc.

Then you could set up some sort of automated mailer to send you an email telling you what ref number was used when they load the page.

This would require some javascript knowledge I believe.  As for the automated mailer, it would be best to deal with it using PHP.  That way you can hide your scripts and keep your information safe, as well as not let them know an email was being sent on page load.

Comment: Thank you Prokzy! Hiding the script in php is an excellent idea. I would have never thought of it. Becki